# How to stop flood of Non-Local IPv6 events in my Console (system.log)?

Tags: macos, console, ipv6

For some reason, my Console is filling up with `<8/15/11 6:47:12.000 PM kernel: IPv6 Non-Local address>` messages. A quick Google doesn't tell me much and there's nothing on some of the usual boards. Any hints? I'm on a MacBook Pro running Lion.

Comment: That's a new one on me. I've never seen that. Perhaps you could capture some ip6 traffic with tcpdump and post it somewhere?

Comment: Well ... Wireshark doesn't show anything going out that matches the time stamps.  I get more "notices" in the console when I fire up safari ... I wonder if it's GlimmerBlocker?

Comment: Confirmed:  This appears as soon as I activate GlimmerBlocker.  I didn't see the behavior under Snow Leopard

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved by turning off GlimmerBlocker.